# Cordova can't read files with FileRead

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm using JavaScript's FileReader API to try to get the blob of a file inside a Cordova application.

My code is like the example below:

```
let reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function (event) {
    console.log(reader.result);
    console.log(event);
}
reader.onloadstart = function (event) {
    console.log(reader.result);
    console.log(event);
}
reader.onloadend = function (event) {
    console.log(reader.result);
    console.log(event);
}
reader.onprogress = function (event) {
    console.log(reader.result);
    console.log(event);
}
reader.onerror = function (event) {
    console.log(reader.result);
    console.log(event);
    const error = reader.error;
    console.log(error);
}
reader.onabort = function (event) {
    console.log(reader.result);
    console.log(event);
}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

When reading an image, the API works correctly, obtaining the content, but with files that are not images, the FileReader's onerror event always returns the message "FileError {code: 1}".

The location of files on the smartphone.

- Image before resolveLocalFileSystemURL: `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADownload%2F1671641692909.jpg`
- Image after resolveLocalFileSystemURL: `file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/1671641692909.jpg` - Success
- File before resolveLocalFileSystemURL: `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADownload%2FExample.pptx`
- File after resolveLocalFileSystemURL: `file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Example.pptx` - Error

What could possibly be happening?

I already tried to read using all possible ways (readAsArrayBuffer, readAsBinaryString, readAsDataURL,readAsText)

Code to Resolve URL:

```
originalLocation = 'content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADownload%2F1671641692909.jpg';

window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(originalLocation, function (newFilepath) { resolveFilePath(newFilepath) });

function resolveFilePath(location) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(location, function (fileEntry) {

        fileEntry.file(function (file) {

            let reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (event) {
                console.log(reader.result);
                console.log(event);
            }
            reader.onloadstart = function (event) {
                console.log(reader.result);
                console.log(event);
            }
            reader.onloadend = function (event) {
                console.log(reader.result);
                console.log(event);
            }
            reader.onprogress = function (event) {
                console.log(reader.result);
                console.log(event);
            }
            reader.onerror = function (event) {
                console.log(reader.result);
                console.log(event);
                const error = reader.error;
                console.log(error);
            }
            reader.onabort = function (event) {
                console.log(reader.result);
                console.log(event);
            }
            console.log(file);
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        });
    });
}
```

config.xml

```
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
       <application requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" />
</edit-config>

<preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,cache,cache-external,assets,root" />
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```